# How to create a object of Type T in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, generics

Initially I was coding in C#.

Recently started with vb.net for my new project.

In C# reflection method, I used to create a object of generic type `T` as such

```
T item= new T()
```

Can anybody please suggest how can I achieve the same thing in VB.Net

```
Dim item As new Type
```

is not compiling . Please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your generic type parameter is `T` then:

```
Dim item As new T
```

Note though that you'll need to have the `New` type constraint on the type parameter:

```
Public Class Foo(Of T As New)

    Public Function Bar() As T

        Dim item As New T
        ...
        Return item

    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Remember that the generic type needs a parameterless constructor.

Comment: @jlvaquero: Valid point. Its possible to deal with constructors with parameters, but requires more messing around.